# allow unauthenticated users to suggest changes, but wait for administrator approval before changing object

Tags: django, django-forms

Assume I have a very simple model:

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique=True)
```

I want to allow unauthenticated users to use a modelform to **suggest changes** to `School` objects, but I want to flag those changes as not yet being seen by an administrator.  Once an administrator approves, I will then make the suggested change to the existing `School` object.

What is the best way to do this?  Do I need to subclass the `School` class, perhaps calling it `UpdateToSchool` and allowing users make suggestions on this subclassed model rather than the target model itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can address this, to have a `SuggestedSchoolEdits` (or something like that) class that would hold attributes such as:

```
class SuggestedSchoolEdits(object):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School) #You could use generic foreign key to extend this to any type - not just school
    field = models.CharField(choices=<list of fields user can edit>)
    value = models.TextField() 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True) #if you want approval for logged in users too
    moderator_approved = models.BooleanField()
    approver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #Whatever else you wish to track
```

Now, when an edit is made, in the view, you can create an object of this type instead of updating the existing object. Once a moderator approves, a `post_save` signal could trigger the update of the `School` object.

This way, you have complete control over which one gets approved, rejected, etc. and you can keep track of suggestions, etc..

Comment: thanks! this is perfect for user suggestions to change text fields.  but what if I want the user to be able to suggest changes on other field types, like ForeignKey fields or ManyToMany Fields? Any ideas on how that could work?

Comment: I think I will have to deal with those separately.  I can have one proposed change model for dealing with text only models, and a separate one for dealing with more complicated fields.

Comment: Well. It is an internal model,so you can store the key value however you want. Foreignkey might just be an alternate representation.  Moreover,you can chamge the story reference type to a generic foreign key